# Dual boot not recognizing Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, boot-repair

I installed Windows 10 then Ubuntu in a dual boot, but now, when I boot the PC, I don't have a Windows 10 option, only Ubuntu. I tried changing a lot of things.

- I updated grub.
- I tried using `sudo nano /etc/grub.d/40_custom` to edit the file, but grub doesn't recognize what I did.
- I ran Boot-Repair and I have this Boot Info Script as a result:

```
              Boot Info Script 0.61      [1 April 2012]

============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

=> No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.

sda1:

File system:       ntfs
Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  
Boot files:        

sda2:

File system:       vfat
Boot sector type:  Unknown
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  
Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi 
                   /efi/ubuntu/fwupx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi 
                   /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi

sda3:

File system:       
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info: 
Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''

sda4:

File system:       ntfs
Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  
Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda5:

File system:       ext4
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info: 
Operating System:  Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab

sda6:

File system:       swap
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info: 

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________ Disque /dev/sda : 465,8 GiB, 500107862016 octets, 976773168 secteurs Unités : sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 octets Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes Disklabel type: gpt

Partition Boot Start Sector End Sector # of Sectors Id System

/dev/sda1 1 976,773,167 976,773,167 ee GPT

GUID Partition Table detected.

Partition Start Sector End Sector # of Sectors System /dev/sda1 2,048 923,647 921,600 Windows Recovery Environment (Windows) /dev/sda2 923,648 1,128,447 204,800 EFI System partition /dev/sda3 1,128,448 1,161,215 32,768 Microsoft Reserved Partition (Windows) /dev/sda4 1,161,216
567,173,119 566,011,904 Data partition (Windows/Linux) /dev/sda5
567,173,120 968,560,639 401,387,520 Data partition (Linux) /dev/sda6 968,560,640 976,771,071 8,210,432 Swap partition (Linux)

"blkid" output:

Device UUID TYPE
LABEL

/dev/sda1 DEBE87A3BE877337 ntfs
/dev/sda2 327F-75AC vfat
/dev/sda3
/dev/sda4 166481BF6481A1DB ntfs
/dev/sda5 5e1e3259-eade-4696-b7f2-ab1448888b3e ext4
/dev/sda6 62b1867d-83c1-4c8c-9fa2-64a4c95527e9 swap

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device Mount_Point Type Options

/dev/sda2 /boot/efi vfat
(rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro) /dev/sda5 / ext4
(rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)

=========================== sda5/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

#
DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE

#
It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub

#
BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ### if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then set have_grubenv=true load_env fi if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then

set default="${next_entry}" set next_entry= save_env next_entry set boot_once=true else set default="0" fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
menuentry_id_option="--id" else menuentry_id_option="" fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}" save_env saved_entry set prev_saved_entry= save_env prev_saved_entry set boot_once=true fi

function savedefault { if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then saved_entry="${chosen}" save_env saved_entry fi } function recordfail { set recordfail=1 if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi } function load_video { if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then insmod all_video else insmod efi_gop insmod efi_uga insmod ieee1275_fb insmod vbe insmod vga insmod video_bochs insmod video_cirrus fi }

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then font=unicode else insmod part_gpt insmod ext2 set root='hd0,gpt5' if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt5 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt5 5e1e3259-eade-4696-b7f2-ab1448888b3e else search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 5e1e3259-eade-4696-b7f2-ab1448888b3e fi font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2" fi

if loadfont $font ; then set gfxmode=auto load_video insmod gfxterm set locale_dir=$prefix/locale set lang=fr_FR insmod gettext fi terminal_output gfxterm if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
set timeout=30 else if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then set timeout_style=menu set timeout=10 # Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is # unavailable. else set timeout=10 fi fi
END /etc/grub.d/00_header
BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ### set menu_color_normal=white/black set

menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray if background_color 44,0,30,0; then clear fi
END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme
BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ### function gfxmode { set gfxpayload="${1}" if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then set

vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7 else set vt_handoff= fi } if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then set linux_gfx_mode=keep else set linux_gfx_mode=text fi else set linux_gfx_mode=text fi else set linux_gfx_mode=keep fi else set linux_gfx_mode=text fi export linux_gfx_mode menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-5e1e3259-eade-4696-b7f2-ab1448888b3e' { recordfail load_video gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode insmod gzio if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi insmod part_gpt insmod ext2 set root='hd0,gpt5' if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt5 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt5 5e1e3259-eade-4696-b7f2-ab1448888b3e else search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 5e1e3259-eade-4696-b7f2-ab1448888b3e fi linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-36-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=5e1e3259-eade-4696-b7f2-ab1448888b3e ro quiet splash $vt_handoff initrd /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-36-generic } submenu 'Options avancées pour Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-5e1e3259-eade-4696-b7f2-ab1448888b3e' { menuentry 'Ubuntu, avec Linux 4.13.0-36-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.13.0-36-generic-advanced-5e1e3259-eade-4696-b7f2-ab1448888b3e' { recordfail load_video gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode insmod gzio if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi insmod part_gpt insmod ext2 set root='hd0,gpt5' if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt5 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt5 5e1e3259-eade-4696-b7f2-ab1448888b3e else search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 5e1e3259-eade-4696-b7f2-ab1448888b3e fi echo 'Chargement de Linux 4.13.0-36-generic…' linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-36-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=5e1e3259-eade-4696-b7f2-ab1448888b3e ro quiet splash $vt_handoff echo 'Chargement du disque mémoire initial…' initrd /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-36-generic } menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.13.0-36-generic (upstart)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.13.0-36-generic-init-upstart-5e1e3259-eade-4696-b7f2-ab1448888b3e' { recordfail load_video gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode insmod gzio if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi insmod part_gpt insmod ext2 set root='hd0,gpt5' if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt5 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt5 5e1e3259-eade-4696-b7f2-ab1448888b3e else search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 5e1e3259-eade-4696-b7f2-ab1448888b3e fi echo 'Chargement de Linux 4.13.0-36-generic…' linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-36-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=5e1e3259-eade-4696-b7f2-ab1448888b3e ro quiet splash $vt_handoff init=/sbin/upstart echo 'Chargement du disque mémoire initial…' initrd /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-36-generic } menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.13.0-36-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.13.0-36-generic-recovery-5e1e3259-eade-4696-b7f2-ab1448888b3e' { recordfail load_video insmod gzio if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi insmod part_gpt insmod ext2 set root='hd0,gpt5' if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt5 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt5 5e1e3259-eade-4696-b7f2-ab1448888b3e else search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 5e1e3259-eade-4696-b7f2-ab1448888b3e fi echo 'Chargement de Linux 4.13.0-36-generic…' linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-36-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=5e1e3259-eade-4696-b7f2-ab1448888b3e ro recovery nomodeset echo 'Chargement du disque mémoire initial…' initrd /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-36-generic } }
END /etc/grub.d/10_linux
BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen
END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen
BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+
END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+
BEGIN /etc/grub.d/25_custom

menuentry "Windows UEFI bootmgfw.efi" { search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root 327F-75AC chainloader (${root})/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi }

menuentry "Windows Boot UEFI loader" { search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root 327F-75AC chainloader (${root})/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi }

menuentry "EFI/ubuntu/fwupx64.efi" { search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root 327F-75AC chainloader (${root})/EFI/ubuntu/fwupx64.efi }

menuentry "EFI/ubuntu/mmx64.efi" { search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root 327F-75AC chainloader (${root})/EFI/ubuntu/mmx64.efi }
END /etc/grub.d/25_custom
BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ### menuentry 'Windows Boot Manager (sur /dev/sda2)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option

'osprober-efi-327F-75AC' { insmod part_gpt insmod fat set root='hd0,gpt2' if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2 327F-75AC else search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 327F-75AC fi chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi } set timeout_style=menu if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then set timeout=10 fi
END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober
BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ### menuentry 'System setup' $menuentry_id_option 'uefi-firmware' { fwsetup }
END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware
BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ### menuentry "Windows 10" { insmod ntfs search --set=root --label WINDOWS_10 --hint hd0,msdos5

ntldr /bootmgr }
This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries. Simply type the
menu entries you want to add after this comment. Be careful not to change
the 'exec tail' line above.
END /etc/grub.d/40_custom
BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ### if [ -f ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then source

${config_directory}/custom.cfg elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then source $prefix/custom.cfg; fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###

=============================== sda5/etc/fstab: ================================
/etc/fstab: static file system information.

#
Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).

#
/ was on /dev/sda5 during installation UUID=5e1e3259-eade-4696-b7f2-ab1448888b3e / ext4

errors=remount-ro 0 1
/boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=327F-75AC /boot/efi vfat umask=0077 0 1
swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation UUID=62b1867d-83c1-4c8c-9fa2-64a4c95527e9 none swap sw
0 0 UUID=327F-75AC /boot/efi vfat defaults 0 1

=================== sda5: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

       GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)

======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc: ========================

Unknown BootLoader on sda2

00000000 eb 58 90 4d 53 44 4f 53 35 2e 30 00 02 02 fe 19 |.X.MSDOS5.0.....| 00000010 02 00 00 00 00 f8 00 00 3f 00 ff 00 00 18 0e 00 |........?.......| 00000020 00 20 03 00 01 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 |. ..............| 00000030 01 00 06 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |................| 00000040 80 01 29 ac 75 7f 32 4e 4f 20 4e 41 4d 45 20 20 |..).u.2NO NAME | 00000050 20 20 46 41 54 33 32 20 20 20 33 c9 8e d1 bc f4 | FAT32 3.....| 00000060 7b 8e c1 8e d9 bd 00 7c 88 56 40 88 4e 02 8a 56 |{......|.V@.N..V| 00000070 40 b4 41 bb aa 55 cd 13 72 10 81 fb 55 aa 75 0a |@.A..U..r...U.u.| 00000080 f6 c1 01 74 05 fe 46 02 eb 2d 8a 56 40 b4 08 cd |...t..F..-.V@...| 00000090 13 73 05 b9 ff ff 8a f1 66 0f b6 c6 40 66 0f b6 |.s......f...@f..| 000000a0 d1 80 e2 3f f7 e2 86 cd c0 ed 06 41 66 0f b7 c9 |...?.......Af...| 000000b0 66 f7 e1 66 89 46 f8 83 7e 16 00 75 39 83 7e 2a |f..f.F..~..u9.~*| 000000c0 00 77 33 66 8b 46 1c 66 83 c0 0c bb 00 80 b9 01 |.w3f.F.f........| 000000d0 00 e8 2c 00 e9 a8 03 a1 f8 7d 80 c4 7c 8b f0 ac |..,......}..|...| 000000e0 84 c0 74 17 3c ff 74 09 b4 0e bb 07 00 cd 10 eb |..t.<.t.........| 000000f0 ee a1 fa 7d eb e4 a1 7d 80 eb df 98 cd 16 cd 19 |...}...}........| 00000100 66 60 80 7e 02 00 0f 84 20 00 66 6a 00 66 50 06 |f`.~.... .fj.fP.| 00000110 53 66 68 10 00 01 00 b4 42 8a 56 40 8b f4 cd 13 |Sfh.....B.V@....| 00000120 66 58 66 58 66 58 66 58 eb 33 66 3b 46 f8 72 03 |fXfXfXfX.3f;F.r.| 00000130 f9 eb 2a 66 33 d2 66 0f b7 4e 18 66 f7 f1 fe c2 |..*f3.f..N.f....| 00000140 8a ca 66 8b d0 66 c1 ea 10 f7 76 1a 86 d6 8a 56 |..f..f....v....V| 00000150 40 8a e8 c0 e4 06 0a cc b8 01 02 cd 13 66 61 0f |@............fa.| 00000160 82 74 ff 81 c3 00 02 66 40 49 75 94 c3 42 4f 4f |.t.....f@Iu..BOO| 00000170 54 4d 47 52 20 20 20 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |TMGR ........| 00000180 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |................| * 000001a0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0d 0a 45 72 |..............Er| 000001b0 72 2e 20 64 69 73 71 75 65 ff 0d 0a 50 72 65 73 |r. disque...Pres| 000001c0 73 65 7a 20 75 6e 65 20 74 6f 75 63 68 65 20 70 |sez une touche p| 000001d0 6f 75 72 20 72 65 64 82 6d 61 72 72 65 72 0d 0a |our red.marrer..| 000001e0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |................| 000001f0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ac 01 ba 01 00 00 55 aa |..............U.| 00000200

=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

cat: /tmp/BootInfo-CA9omQ7R/Tmp_Log: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
```

Do you have any ideas?

I can access Windows in safe mode with the options:

```
menuentry "Windows UEFI bootmgfw.efi" { search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root 327F-75AC chainloader (${root})/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi }

menuentry "Windows Boot UEFI loader" { search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root 327F-75AC chainloader (${root})/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi }
```

but it doesn't enter in other way than safe mode.

Comment: First line says 'No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda' have you tried 'sudo update-grub' and then 'sudo grub-install /dev/sda'?

Comment: Yes, I did, and it's always the same problem. It looks like this message is only because I'm using UEFI and GPT partition.

Comment: when I edited the file, I wrote :
"menuentry "Windows 10" {
   insmod ntfs
   search --set=root --label WINDOWS_10 --hint hd0,msdos5
   ntldr /bootmgr
}"
But maybe this was the wrong thing to write because it's not recognizing.

Comment: Well, I found the solution. It was simply my Windows booting alone in safe mode always. I did Windows+R->msconfig->boot:normal. And everything is solved. Should I suppress my message as it's not a problem of boot but a Windows config problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 was always booting only in **Safe Mode**. Press <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> -> type `msconfig` -> click *OK* button -> *Boot* tab -> uncheck *Safe boot* -> click *Apply* button -> click *OK* button.